# HighCharts : dataLabels errorBar

Tags: highcharts

I want to add on my chart (errorBar type), the min and max values ​​of each point.

as the following link: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-datalabels-align-left/)

I can do it on my various graphics with the following code:

```
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        style: {
            font: 'bold 11px Arial',
            textShadow: '0 0 3px white, 0 0 3px white '
        }
   }
```

Is it possible to do?
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug (or at least an oversite) with highcharts.  I can't find any combination of [dataLabels](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels) options that'll work with an `errorbar` type chart.  If you really need this ability, I'd resort to doing it myself with a `Renderer.text` call:

```
function(chart){
    var points = chart.series[0].points;
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
        var p = points[i];
        chart.renderer.text("High: "+p.high, p.plotX+chart.plotLeft-20, p.highPlot+chart.plotTop-5).add();
        chart.renderer.text("Low: "+p.low, p.plotX+chart.plotLeft-20, p.lowPlot+chart.plotTop+12).add();
}
```

Results in (fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vd4H8/)):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it looks like a bug, so I reported it https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2770

Answer (score 0):

For people still searching for this:

Highchart fixed the labels for the error bars. You can now place a custom high and low label using data labels and custom formatter

```
 dataLabels: {
        inside: false,
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
          return (this.point.y == this.point.high ? "High: " : "Low: ") + this.point.y
        }
      }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/amalborn/5xLzn204/1/